# Postgresql jsonb selecting different elements of array (with the same keys) in a row

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Using this jsonb:

```
[
    {
        "#text": "ANNALS OF THE RHEUMATIC DISEASES",
        "@type": "source"
    },
    {
        "#text": "ANN RHEUM DIS",
        "@type": "source_abbrev"
    },
    {
        "#text": "Ann. Rheum. Dis.",
        "@type": "abbrev_iso"
    },
    {
        "#text": "ANN RHEUM D",
        "@type": "abbrev_11"
    },
    {
        "#text": "ANN RHEUM DIS",
        "@type": "abbrev_29"
    },
    {
        "#text": "Comparison of initial versus delayed introduction of a treat-to-target strategy in patients with recent-onset rheumatoid arthritis: results of the T-4 3-year study",
        "@type": "item"
    }
]
```

I can do a selection like this:

```
select b.x->>'#text' from b 
where b.x @> '{"@type" : "source"}'::jsonb
```

but what I want is to select for example the #text where the key is "item", "abbrev_iso"  and "source"  in one row.  Can this be done in plain SQL or is it better to write a function to do help with the query?

The result must look something like this:

```
Source                                 Abbrev                Item
ANNALS OF THE RHEUMATIC DISEASES       Ann. Rheum. Dis.      Comparison of initial versus....
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works.  Initial tests showed that on 10000 records it is about 8 times slower than getting the same result joining 3 traditonal tables.

```
with a as
  (select id,
          xml_json#>'{titles,title}' y
   from source),
     items as
  ( select id,
           e.item ->> '#text' as text_val,
                      e.item ->> '@type' as type
   from a,
        jsonb_array_elements(a.y) as e(item))
select b.id,
       j.text_val source,
                  i.text_val item,
                  ab.text_val abbrev
from items b
left join items j on j.id = b.id
and j.type = 'source'
left join items i on i.id = b.id
and i.type = 'item'
left join items ab on ab.id = b.id
and ab.type = 'abbrev_iso'
```